# Edit C:/windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I tried to edit the file C:/windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts in Windows 10 using a (the only one created) administrative user account ("john") but not able to save the file.  I note from various websites that although the Administrators group has Modify permission of the folder C:/windows/system32/drivers/etc, this only applies to the disabled built-in "administrator" account (even though john is in the Administrators group, as shown in lusrmgr.msc). So I added john to the permission.  I also found that the owner of the folder is TrustedInstaller, so I changed it to john.  I checked that the effective permissions of john for the folder and the hosts file do include read/write/modify.  However when I try to save the hosts file, Windows still say access is denied.  Please help.  Thanks.

Comment: Open Notepad elevated, then open and edit the hosts file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to work with `hosts` file is to run your editor as Administrator and then open `hosts` file for edit.

Comment: This is correct - it's a UAC issue.